# Computing the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution.

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Let $f(x)=x_1|x|^\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $\alpha > n-1$. We have to compute $\hat{f}(\xi)$. The hint says to compute $(d/dx_1)(|x|^{\alpha+2})$. I don't quite understand how I should go about on solving the question.

Really appreciate the help! thanks!

Comment: The problem is to find the Fourier transform of $|x|^\alpha$, then multiplication by $x_1$ amounts to differentiation of its Fourier transform with respect to $\xi_1$. It is not too hard to find the Fourier transform of $|x|^\alpha$. It is radial thus so is its Fourier transform, and $F[|x|^\alpha](r\xi)= F[r^{-n} |x/r|^\alpha](\xi)=r^{-n-\alpha}F[|x|^\alpha]( \|\xi\|)$

Comment: @reuns what exactly do you mean by multiplication by $x_1$ amounts to differentiation of its fourier transform?

Comment: This is the main property of the Fourier transform, it switches derivative and multiplication by the variable